# Thread Safe API for TIMEZONE conversion

Tags: unix, timezone

Is there a thread safe apis in C/C++ for converting time from one time zone to another ?
There are apis like localtime_r etc which reads TZ env variable . Setting the TZ env variable will create problems if you have multiple threads using localtime_r .Any suggestions ?

Comment: for the time being  unix platforms i am looking for some thing in stdlib

Comment: People often read tz database directly (by copying tzfile.{h,c}) and use the database to do timezone conversions without using TZ variable. Not sure if there is an open-source project for that.

Comment: I would love to have a non-boost-heavy, thread-safe library to do time zone conversions.  I would love it very, very much.  However, from what I can tell, there isn't one.  I did make the open source time zone code used in many OSS unix-like systems thread safe, but maintenance is a pain...  and I can't release the result yet.